# The comparison between the columns of a Matrix by an algebraic relationship

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming, linear-algebra

I am trying to work a program using Mathematica to Compare the columns of the matrix `bb` by applying an algebraic formula .

I will give a simple example explaining the mathematical process if it can help me write the program. For example, consider a matrix `bb` of size ($4\times 5$)

```
bb = {{1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}}
```

[image]

To illustrate the algebraic process we will represent the matrix `bb` in the form of a table,

```
TableForm[Normal[bb], 
     TableHeadings -> {{"r1", "r2", "r3", "r4"}, {"c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", 
        "c5"}}]
```

[image]

I want to make a comparison between the columns depend on this algebraic equation

if $a_{ij}+a_{ik}\neq 0$ $\forall i$  then type $c_jc_k$

if $a_{ij}+a_{ik}+a_{im}\neq 0$ $\forall i$  then type $c_jc_kc_m$

if $a_{ij}+a_{ik}+a_{im}\neq 0+\ldots+a_{i\text{#}}$ $\forall i$  then type $c_jc_kc_m\ldots c_{\text{#}}$

Clarify the mathematical steps on the example as follows

Steps

1- 
$a_{i1}+a_{i2}\neq 0$ $\forall i$

$a_{i1}+a_{i3}= 0$ for $i=2$

$a_{i1}+a_{i4}= 0$ for $i=2$

$a_{i1}+a_{i5}= 0$ for $i=4$

$a_{i2}+a_{i3}= 0$ for $i=1$

$a_{i2}+a_{i4}= 0$ for $i=3$

$a_{i2}+a_{i5}= 0$ for $i=1$

$a_{i3}+a_{i4}= 0$ for $i=2$

$a_{i1}+a_{i2}= 0$ for $i=1$

$a_{i4}+a_{i5}\neq 0$ $\forall i$

then we type only $c_1c_2$ and $c_4c_5$

2- for 3 column 
we get 8 cases successes
$a_{ij}+a_{ik}+a_{im}\neq 0$ $\forall i$

3- for 4 column 
all $a_{ij}+a_{ik}+a_{im}+a_{in}= 0$ in some i

4-for 5 column 
all $a_{ij}+a_{ik}+a_{im}+a_{in}+a_{iw}= 0$ in some i

5- type S={all successes case in 4 steps}={$c_1c_2$,$c_4c_5$,...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find column subsets where the minimum of the sum of the columns is greater than 0 (however, you say that there are no column subsets with 4 or 5 members, so I'm probably misunderstanding something). At any rate, one way to do this is to take a dot product of your matrix with a "column selecting" matrix, and finding the minimum. Here is your matrix:

```
bb = {{1,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,0,1},{0,1,1,1,0}};
bb //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Here is the "column selecting" matrix:

```
sets = Tuples[{0, 1}, 5];
sets
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1,
>      0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 
>     0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 
>     1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0,
>      1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1,
>      0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 
>     1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 
>     0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

Finally, here is the dot product that adds column subsets:

```
sets . Transpose[bb]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 
>     2, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 
>     2}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 
>     3}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 0, 2, 
>     1}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 0, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 
>     1}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 
>     3}, {2, 2, 3, 3}}

The column subsets you're interested in can be extracted using [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick):

```
r = Pick[p, Unitize[Min /@ (sets . Transpose[bb])], 1]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1,
>      1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 
>     0}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 
>     1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

We can convert the above representations of the subsets into the version you asked for with:

```
Sort[r . Array[Subscript[c, #]&, 5] /. Plus -> Times] //TeXForm
```

> $\left\{c_1 c_2,c_1 c_2 c_3,c_1 c_2 c_4,c_2 c_3 c_4,c_1 c_2 c_3 c_4,c_1 c_2 c_5,c_1 c_3
>    c_5,c_1 c_2 c_3 c_5,c_4 c_5,c_1 c_4 c_5,c_2 c_4 c_5,c_1 c_2 c_4 c_5,c_3 c_4 c_5,c_1
>    c_3 c_4 c_5,c_2 c_3 c_4 c_5,c_1 c_2 c_3 c_4 c_5\right\}$

*Update to remove supersets*

If we want to delete supersets, we can use [`DeleteDuplicates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicates):

```
b = DeleteDuplicates[r, #1 #2 == #1&]
Sort[b . Array[Subscript[c, #]&, 5] /. Plus -> Times] //TeXForm
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0}}
>
> $\left\{c_1 c_2,c_2 c_3 c_4,c_1 c_3 c_5,c_4 c_5\right\}$

Comment: Great job I owe you to help
. Can you add the condition to delete each limit containing $c_1c_2$ or $c_4c_5$ then s={$c_1c_2,c_4c_5,c_1c_3c_5,c_2c_3c_4$}